# WordPress site <a href=""></a> is not working with lightbox

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress

I'm facing problem in WordPress site.

Following is my code:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com">
  <img width="288" height="590" alt="advertisement-1"
  src="http://www.modusliberty.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Resurrection_Aromatique_Hand_Balm_75ml_0.jpg"
  class="aligncenter wp-image-746 size-full"></a>
```

Currently when I click on the image then it opens in lightbox, but I want that when I click on the image then https://www.google.com url is opened in new window.

Comment: Try removing `rel="nobox"` from your `<a>`

Comment: not working after removing rel="nobox"

Comment: You need to add for all images or just this one only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try like this using css:

```
<a class="lightbox" href="#goofy">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/158388/goofy.jpg"/>
</a> 
<div class="lightbox-target" id="goofy">
   <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/158388/goofy.jpg"/>
   <a class="lightbox-close" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Then css would be like :

```
*Eliminates padding, centers the thumbnail */
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Styles the thumbnail */
a.lightbox img {
  height: 150px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 94px 20px 20px 20px;
}

/* Styles the lightbox, removes it from sight and adds the fade-in transition */
.lightbox-target {
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Styles the lightbox image, centers it vertically and horizontally, adds the zoom-in transition and makes it responsive using a combination of margin and absolute positioning */
.lightbox-target img {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-height: 0%;
  max-width: 0%;
  border: 3px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

/* Styles the close link, adds the slide down transition */
a.lightbox-close {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

/* Provides part of the "X" to eliminate an image from the close link */
a.lightbox-close:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 1px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 26px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

/* Provides part of the "X" to eliminate an image from the close link */
a.lightbox-close:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 1px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 26px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

/* Uses the :target pseudo-class to perform the animations upon clicking the .lightbox-target anchor */
.lightbox-target:target {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.lightbox-target:target img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.lightbox-target:target a.lightbox-close {
  top: 0px;
}
```

Please see the link for more description: http://www.designcouch.com/home/why/2013/11/01/responsive-css3-lightbox-with-no-javascript/ OR we can use css like here http://codepen.io/gschier/pen/HCoqh

Comment: no.........................
i don't want to use lightbox dear..
my problem is that my <a href=""> is not working when i click on a image. Because of when i click on image then image is open in lightbox but i want to do when i click on image then browser is ....

Comment: you didnt mentioned that specifically earlier